# A way to get BCC recipients from a email on S3 (SES email receiving)

Tags: amazon-ses

I am using SES inbound that stores the raw messages in S3. Emails get into a bucket and then I have a script that parses every email in the bucket and extracts **all the email recipients**.

The problem is that sometimes, with emails where all recipients are in BCC, there is no way to know who are the recipients, there is no header with the values in the raw email. Seems that looking to the raw there is no way to get the BCC recipients.

How can I know which are the real addresses the mail was originally destined to? Perhaps there is a way to add a custom header to the raw with the recipients or playing with some SES API and the `X-SES-RECEIPT`, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same concerns, right from an AWS engineer:

In order to receive useful metadata like the recipients the message was delivered to (without having to parse headers), I recommend subscribing to SNS notifications for emails received with your S3 action.

The 'recipients' field of the notifications will contain the information you are looking for. More details on contents here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-notifications-contents.html

More info on the SNS topic property of the S3 action can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a Received header that contains a '... for email@foo.com;' address within it.  However, i've seen it both as '... for email@foo.com;' and as '... for ;'.  So it is a little tricky to parse out.

E.g. in this case the recipient is: email.foo.com

```
Received: from mail-qt0-f876.google.com (mail-qt0-f876.google.com [209.85.216.176])
 by inbound-smtp.us-west-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id 8t8gp7m0c81g6ddn1g8b7klev4cnlup039tuhlg1
 for test@email.foo.com;
 Thu, 12 Oct 2017 00:51:01 +0000 (UTC)
```

I've also seen (even in the same message):

```
Received: by mail-qt0-f876.google.com with SMTP id v41so999755qtv.12
    for <test@email.foo.com>; Wed, 11 Oct 2017 17:51:01 -0700 (PDT)
```